# Animated movie about flood with female turtle as twist villain

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I am trying to identify an animated movie.  I owned a DVD around 10-15 years ago.

It's about a boy, a girl, the boy's dad and an African woman playing as the mother figure for the boy (I don't remember if she was the boy's actual mother) surviving a flood with their farm animals by converting their shed into a house-boat. They use a tractor as the engine and stockpile potatoes to feed the animals fries. At one point there's a conflict between the carnivores that don't want to eat fries and the herbivores. A turtle that lures crocodiles to the boat is revealed as a twist villain.

At the end of the movie the flood is over and the girl is reunited with her parents.

I would be really happy if someone knows this obscure movie.

This movie may be originally in German. I don't even know if a English release exists.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The wording of your first sentence is unclear, but do I understand correctly that you _had_ the disk 10 years ago and no longer have it?  Do you remember what the cover art on the case was?

Comment: Additionally, what farm animals are carnivorous that they would have problems with?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I remember reading a book with this story. Among the carnivorous animals were a bear. Somehow, they could communicate with each others and the humans. The carnivorous ones were all afraid of the father, so they decided to overthrow his ruling by getting rid of him. They managed to take him by surprise and get rid of him and the boy's mother by sending them into a small boat or something. Later on, as the mother turtle (who was leading the rebellion) is talking with "her" eggs in her hands, the twist is that it's actually a boy (we can see his genitals), and the eggs hatch with baby crocodiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like it might be [*Raining Cats and Frogs*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365659/) a 2003 animated children's movie.

Quoting the plot summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raining_Cats_and_Frogs#Plot):

> Ferdinand Bauer lives with his wife Juliette on a farm on a hill with their adoptive son (actually his grandson), Tom. The film begins when they agree to care of Lili, his other granddaughter, whom they will look after while Lili's parents travel by car and trailer to Africa to find crocodiles for their zoo, which they also leave in the care of Ferdinand and Juliette.
>
> On the farm, there is a small pond. The frogs in the pond are restless, as their calculations have shown that the Earth is about to be flooded for forty days and forty nights. The frogs initially are reluctant to tell them, since they cannot change anything but decide to tell Tom and Lili, so that they can warn people.
>
> Suddenly the flood starts, apparently washing away all live on Earth. **The zoo animals escape to the barn which is on top of a hill, the foundations of the building are torn away by the flood and floats on a huge tractor tire on the water**. Ferdinand, an experienced sailor, takes on the role of the captain and every one agrees that they will only survive if they stick together. When the rains finally stop all the animals are very hungry. **Ferdinand has stored 28 tons of potatoes which he uses to make French fries, but the carnivores are unhappy because they cannot survive only on French fries** but Ferdinand convinces the carnivores to yield in view of the greater good of everyone on the floating barn.
>
> [...]
>
> The tortoise tells Lili her story of how she saved her life and three of her eggs despite losing her limb to the crocodiles, who attacked everyone, including humans, at the time of the flood and convinces Lili that her parents died. Ferdinand and Juliette adopt Lili as their own. At night **the carnivores notice that the tortoise is actually in cahoots with the crocodiles to feed the entire barn to them**, but she must get rid of the captain. The carnivores are initially unconvinced, but they latter agree to mutiny and in the ensuing fight they throw Ferdinand off the board in a barrel and Juliette jumps off after him. The rest of the animals and the children are locked away at the bottom of the barn. Lili sees now that she fell into the tortoise's trap, who had told her that she would not be her friend if she continued being friends with Tom.
>
> [...]
>
> A few days go by and the kittens are born. The general happiness is interrupted when the elephants, who have been unable to move during all their time in the barn, appear at the door to congratulate the proud mother. Ferdinand walks out of the barn and sees that the water has finally gone and that dryland is finally there. There is a lot of mist and as it lifts, all the people and animals at the barn see that there are more boats on the top of other mountains and that there are many survivors. Later that night all celebrate but a huge light interrupts the festivities, it is **a large car driven by Lili's parents, who tell the rest that the flood did not take place in Africa**.

The trailer on YouTube (props to FuzzyBoots):

Comment: I'm going to yield to you because you took the step of highlighting relevant bits. Do you want the trailer link of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYnR0nIasxA ?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots That would be handy, yes.  Thank you.

Comment: This is definitely the story I remembered upon reading the question title; although I haven't watched the movie but read the book.

Comment: Trivia: The French title is _"La prophétie des grenouilles"_ (translated into _"The frogs' prohecy"_ ) because as the story starts, the boy and the girl encounters some frogs who warn them about the incoming storm, which will flood the world for _"40 days and 40 nights"_ and that's how they knew to get ready for it.

Comment: This is it, you are my hero